# python error: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
T = 3000
def Intensity(nu, T):
  (2 * h * nu**3) / ((c**2) * (exp((h * nu)/(k * T)) - 1))
  return Intensity
plt.plot (nu, Intensity)
plt.xlabel ('Frequency [hertz]')
plt.ylabel ('Intensity')
plt.title ('Stellar Temperature vs. Intensity')
plt.show()
```

When I run the code, I get the error:

```
float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'
```

I don't really understand the error. I'm trying to create a function that describes the intensity as a function of temperature and frequency (nu) and then fix the temperature to plot a graph between frequency and intensity.

Comment: What is `h`? You should be passing in two arrays for the arguments to `.plot()`, e.g. from `.linspace()`.

Comment: You should always provide tracebacks for your errors.

Comment: Also, post complete code without missing variable definitions

Answer (score 1):

A common misconception among beginners is that `plt.plot` plots functions. It doesn't. All it plots is sets of x-y points, sometimes connected by lines.

Given this information, it should be more clear that `plt.plot` has no idea what to do with `Intensity`, especially since it accepts not one but two arguments.

The remedy is to evaluate `Intensity` at the locations corresponding to `nu`. Let's assume that `nu` is a numpy array generated with something like `np.arange`, `np.linspace`, `np.geomspace`, `np.logspace`, etc. In that case you can do

```
i = Intensity(nu, T)
plt.plot(nu, i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Intensity function returns a reference to itself. The arithmetic within the function achieves nothing